# Sequelize - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: include, sequelize.js, sql-order-by

I'm stuck here for 4 days. Also this is my first post. I'm getting this error using sequelize select with includes, through and OrderBy

**'The multi-part identifier "ProposalCust.email" could not be bound.'**

I'm trying to order my select by email with ASC or DESC order and I'm building an object orderObject first:

> orderObject = [[{model: models.Customer, as: 'ProposalCust'}, 'email',
>   'ASC']]

The select is the next:

```
return models.Proposal.findAndCountAll({
            order: [orderObject],
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Customer,
                        through: {
                        where: {
                            roleId: 1
                        }
                    },  
                    where: {},
                    as: 'ProposalCust',
                },
            ]
        })
            .then(res => res)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
};
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Sequelize.literal` to order records by email as follows -

```
return models.Proposal.findAndCountAll({
            order: [[Sequelize.literal('`ProposalCust`.`email`'), 'ASC']],
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Customer,
                        through: {
                        where: {
                            roleId: 1
                        }
                    },  
                    where: {},
                    as: 'ProposalCust',
                },
            ]
        })
            .then(res => res)
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
};
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Getting this error:
"Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement. "

Comment: Can you please share the query after commenting `order` clause in the Sequelize statement?

Comment: What do you  mean, select result? It does correctly the select if I comment clause 'order'

Comment: I need you to post SQL query generated by Sequelize after commenting order clause